# Pass parameter into sed command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script in which the user can pass a regex as a parameter. So for example you run the program this way.

```
./clean_txt.sh s/.*\(my_choices.*gz\)/\1p
```

In the program, I am using that parameter this way.

```
ls /home/user/ | sed -n '$1' > cleaned_file.txt
echo "sed -n '$1'"
```

In my echo, I see the regular expression passed when when program was initiated. But my cleaned_file.txt is empty. The only way this works is if I hardcode the a regular expression into the program itself but that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do.

Any idea on how I can pass that parameter into the sed command?

Comment: Add a `/` at the end of your regex.

Comment: @Cyrus I guess that the `p` is a print command, so it would be `/\1/p`. That doesn't necessarily explain why it would work when hard-coded but not as a variable.

Comment: @Tom Fenech: That's right.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your variable is not being expanded. You need to wrap it in double quotes (which is what you're doing in the `echo` already):

```
ls /home/user/ | sed -n "$1" > cleaned_file.txt
```

Note that `ls` is not needed:

```
files=( /home/user/* )
sed -n "$1" <<<"${files[@]}" > cleaned_file.txt
```

Would do the same thing. This uses a glob to create an array containing all the filenames, which is used as input to sed.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to pass the result of the glob directly to sed, which is a shame.

Comment: This didn't work. But that is okay.  This is the script i am actually trying to run. Unfortunately there is no way to pass the variable $regex into the script. I have to hardcode it. When I do, I get an error. 
    `prefix="s3://${s3_bucket}/${s3_folder}/$(date --date="$i days ago" +"%Y/%m/%d")/"
    aws s3 ls s3://${s3_bucket}/${s3_folder}/$(date --date="$i days ago" +"%Y/%m/%d")/ | sed -n "'$regex'" | awk -v myprefix="$prefix" '{ print myprefix $0 }' >> ${s3_files_final}`

Comment: You should edit your question to include that code. Also, show how you are calling the script and include any specific error messages that you are getting.

Comment: `sed -n "'$1'"` will pass the single-quotes to `sed`, so the program `sed` tries to execute will be `'s/.../.../'`, which is not valid syntax since `'` is not a `sed` command. You need `sed -n "$1"`. Also, when the calling the script, it's important to backslash-escape the backslash in the replacement: `s/.../\\1/p`; otherwise, the pattern will be replaced with a single digit `1`, which is probably not what was intended.

Comment: @rici good points, thanks. Feel free to edit, otherwise will do so later

Comment: @rici Your suggestion worked. I didn't have to backslash-escape the replacement. Not an expert user of sed and regexes, simply letting you know. I won't have gotten this far without all your help! Tom French, thank you.

Comment: @Tokunbo as I said before, if you edit your question to include the full code you are using, I can add to my answer. Otherwise, you can accept my answer to mark your problem as solved and upvote it if you found it useful.